# implement single sign on(saml2) in reactjs without express

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I want to implement SSO SAML2 with wso2 ei in React where

1. I go to check if I am  authenticated or not
2. If not authenticated I should redirect to sso URL
3. When I sign in successfully on sso identity provider, I redirect to my react app with token
4. Then save token to localstorage and go ahead

I have tried it with Passport and Express where rendering is happening on server side. But I want it on the client side with React, steps:

1. I go to my home page and click on login page
2. It take me to wso2 identity provider and then I login
3. Then I redirect to my express app

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: you can't do that.

You cannot use SAML without a backend. SAML requires you to register a Sercice Provider (SP), which must be identifiable with an SSL cerificate. Therefore the SP must have a private key, which you cannot distribute to a browser client for obvious reasons. On top of that, the assertion endpoint should accept a POST HTTP request, which traditionally only a server can do.

You can skip the IdP discovery if you know which IdP you wish to use, but the assertion phase cannot be circumvented. You must have an assertion endpoint for the SSO. This endpoint must be able to decrypt messages encrypted with the public key of the SP, so it must be implemented on a server.

To get as close to what you want as possible, you can implement the SP as a separate microservice that only has one (or two if you're utilizing the DS) endpoint(s). The assertion endpoint of your login service can create a token for the user and redirect them to the frontend carrying the token in a query variable.

Comment: I left that part ambiguous because it's up to your application. I'll give you an example, but you can do it in any way you wish to. You can create and verify tokens with the npm package `jsonwebtoken`. Create a token with `sign(value, SECRET)` in your login service and save it in the browser. Browser sends token to another service and you can verify it with `verify(token, SECRET)`. There's no need to send the secret between the two services. Just make sure they both have the same secret.

Comment: @JemiSalo - I understand a backend is required, but in case backend and frontend are hosted separately how will it work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120582/java-sprint-boot-react-application-sso-azure-ad

Comment: @Varun If you want to verify outside the signing backend server you can use a private-public key pair instead of a single secret. Sign using the private key on one trusted server. You can then safely expose the public key with an API endpoint. Any service can then request the public key from the trusted server and use it to verify tokens.