# SAML Identity provider Authentication

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, saml-2.0

I am developing an application in which my company has already set-up **SAML IBM on-premises identity provider**. My problem is I need to integrate that in SPA and asp.net core web API. I have done a lot of research on google and read various articles but haven't anything fruitful.

My scenario is -
User/browser -> SPA(application built using **react js**) -> Identity Provider UI(for authentication) -> User enters credentials -> Redirected back to SPA -> Saves token in browser -> calls **asp.net core web API**(passing same token received from identity provider) -> verifies token with Identity provider -> calls action method(if authorized/authenticated) -> returns data to SPA.

Please help me I am stuck on this. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You have basically put your project requirement as a post here. without giving clarity on what you are stuck at! Based on the post you don't seem stuck but haven't even got started. Since you have tagged asp.net  and SAML 2.0. here is one of the articles https://developers.onelogin.com/saml and  POC https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml from Onelogin I initially referred to develop code at the Service Provider end.

Comment: Hi @AkshayGaonkar, thank you for pointing to the links. Sorry, if I didn't mention my problem appropriately. I am stuck how can we navigate away from react application to our Identity provider.  Because the blogs which I found are usually using backend(either Asp.Net MVC application or node js) to navigate to IDP. Then IDP redirects to backend application. My question is 'Is there a way in which user can navigate to IDP from react application and IDP should send back response to callback method of react application not to my backend application' P.S - I am new to SAML.

Comment: I don’t have any  expertise on reactjs. but see if this post helps you to get some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418295/implement-single-sign-onsaml2-in-reactjs-without-express

Comment: SAML isn't appropriate for React. OIDC using OAuth Code flow is, though. Your IdP (or OIDC Provider) should have a mechanism to support that.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewK. for helping me out. It really cleared out the things.

Comment: Thank you @AkshayGaonkar for pointing out the link. It really helped me.

Comment: @Rahul it's just a POC Code that will get you started. It does not cover all security checks that SAML demands and there is no code to retrieve attribute lists from assertions.   You can always use the other SAML toolkit mentioned in the GitHub link or build your own code.